# Having problem with opening same files openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

Writting a program, that shuffels contents in files. All files are almost the same, but it doesn't work for some of them. Can't understand.

```
for file in allFiles:
print(file)
items = []
fileName = file
fileIndex = 1
directory = os.path.join(path, fileName[:-5].strip())
if not os.path.exists(directory):
    os.mkdir(directory)
    
theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
allSheetNames = theFile.sheetnames
```

And after some quantity of files, it shows me these errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\staff\Python\NewProject\glow.py", line 25, in <module>
    theFile = openpyxl.load_workbook(file)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 313, in load_workbook
    reader = ExcelReader(filename, read_only, keep_vba,
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 124, in __init__
    self.archive = _validate_archive(fn)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\reader\excel.py", line 96, in _validate_archive
    archive = ZipFile(filename, 'r')
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1269, in __init__
    self._RealGetContents()
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\zipfile.py", line 1336, in _RealGetContents
    raise BadZipFile("File is not a zip file")
zipfile.BadZipFile: File is not a zip file
```

But before that everything worked fine, there was no error. Can someone guess, why? Thanks, everybody.
Looking for files that way:

```
path = os.getcwd()
sourcePath = os.getcwd() + '\source'
extension = 'xlsx'
os.chdir(sourcePath)
allFiles = glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You iterate over all files not regarding the filetype. Probably you or a process added a file to the directory which is no xlsx file. This is why openpyxl fails to read it.

Comment: Added how i look for all files.